# Unexpected end of subtree with Criteria Query using isEmpty

Tags: spring, hibernate, oracle11g, criteria

I've ran into a problem while developing a Spring Boot application with Criteria API.

I'm having a simple `Employer` entity, which contains a set of `Job.ID` (not entities, they're pulled out using repository when needed). `Employer` and `Job` are in many to many relationship. This mapping is only used on a purpose of finding Employee with no jobs.

```
public class Employer {

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
        name = "EMPLOYEE_JOBS"
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID")
    @Column(name = "JOB_ID")
    private final Set<String> jobs = new HashSet<>(); //list of ids of jobs for an employee 
}
```

Then I have a generic function, which returns a predicate (Specification) by a given attributePath and command for any `IEntity` implementation.

```
public <E extends IEntity> Specification<E> createPredicate(String attributePath, String command) {
    return (r, q, b) -> {
        Path<?> currentPath = r;
        for(String attr : attributePath.split("\\.")) {
            currentPath = currentPath.get(attr);
        }

        if(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(currentPath.getJavaType())) {
            //currentPath points to PluralAttribute
            if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("empty")) {
                return b.isEmpty((Expression<Collection<?>>)currentPath);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If want to get list of all employee, who currently have no job, I wish I could create the predicate as follows:

```
Specification<Employer> spec = createPredicate("jobs", "empty");

//or if I want only `Work`s whose were done by employer with no job at this moment
Specification<Work> spec = createPredicate("employerFinished.jobs", "empty");
```

This unfortunately does not works and throws following exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected end of subtree 
[select generatedAlias0 from Employer as generatedAlias0 
where generatedAlias0.jobs is empty]
```

Is there a workaround how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

This bug in Hibernate is known since September 2011, but sadly hasn't been fixed yet. (Update: this bug is fixed as of 5.4.11)

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6686

Luckily there is a very easy workaround, instead of:

```
"where generatedAlias0.jobs is empty"
```

you can use

```
"where size(generatedAlias0.jobs) = 0"
```

This way the query will work as expected.